# Does $V= \ker T \oplus \operatorname{im} T$ imply diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, diagonalization

(FYI: I posted this same question very recently but think I accidentally deleted it. Sorry for the repost.)

**For $V$ finite dimensional, if $V= \ker T \oplus \operatorname{im} T$, is $T$ necessarily diagonalizable?** I'm guessing that it's not true and am looking for a counterexample.

By the way, I saw that when I posted this question earlier, someone answered by offering the counterexample $T(x,y)=(y,x)$ where $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$. But I think this wouldn't work, since $T$ has eigenvalues $\pm 1$.

Comment: I replied in the previous post and there was a small typo because writing in LaTeX by cell is very bad. The correct would be $T(x,y)=(-y,x)$ where $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @M.Lobo Oh , got it. Sorry for deleting it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual counterexample works:
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$
has one eigenvalue (namely $1$), so it has trivial kernel, and its columns form a basis, so it has image the whole of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and indeed $\mathbb{R}^2 = \{0\} \oplus \mathbb{R}^2$, so it satisfies the conditions in the question. It is also famously not diagonalisable.

Comment: Nice explanation and example.

Comment: Thank you!. We could also say since it's injective and an operator on $\mathbb{R}^2$, it must be surjective as well, right?

Comment: That is true of any operator on a finite dimensional vector space.

Answer (score 3):

No, take $$T=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1&1\\
0&1
\end{array}\right)$$
This matrix is not diagonalizable, but it is surjective, so it satisfies the direct sum decomposition in your statement trivially since $V$ is the image.

Comment: Nice counterexample. Could you tell me what is the result that relates subjectivity of linear transformation to direct sum decomposition? Thanks

Comment: Ah! Surjective and finite dimensional means trivial kernel. It wasnt necessary for the direct sum, but it made it easier. The key was looking for a map that wasn't diagonalizable, and then asking if it provided a direct sum decomposition. Thankfully this classic example had an easy image and kernel to compute.

Comment: In terms of diagonalizability, you can't do better than having a basis of eigenvectors. A direct sum decomposition needn't provide you with much in the way of eigenvectors.

Comment: Oh great thought. I missed this. +1 already given :)