# If $T:V \to V$ and $T$ is surjective, can i say that $T$ is diagonaizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If $T:V \to V$ and $T$ is surjective, can i say that $T$ is diagonaizable?

I can surley say that $T$ is invertible, but what is the relation to diagonaizability, if there is one?

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2266568/does-v-ker-t-oplus-operatornameim-t-imply-diagonalizable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot, e.g. the map $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1& 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
is surjective but not diagonalizable.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to $T$ a scalar operator (a multiple of the identity map) does not change the diagonalizability, but it may change the invertibility! So there cannot be a relation between invertibility and diagonalizability.

That is, assuming $V$ is a finite dimensional real vector space, for every real number $a$, the operator $T - a \cdot \operatorname{id}$ is diagonalizable iff $T$ is diagonalizable. But for some $a$ this operator is not invertible (to be precise, those $a$ are the roots of the characteristic polynomial of $T$), and for some $a$ it is invertible (equivalently, surjective).

Comment: I dont fully understand, what is $T-aid$? and what is "iff $T$ is."?

Comment: I expanded my answer

Comment: Thank you for the answer, good point, change of invertibility, but unchange diagonaizability.